# Action button in Shiny app updates query in url with input from user

Tags: r, shiny

I have this app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("query_text","Type something:"),
  actionButton(inputId='query_button',
               label="Search", 
               icon = icon("th"), 
               onclick = paste("location.href='http://www.example.com?lookfor=",
                               input$query_text, "'", sep=""))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd like to update the url with the action button, so when the user types something (for example: paper), it updates the url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?lookfor=paper
```

Any ideias how to do it? Maybe wrapping it on a observeEvent?

Comment: Are you trying to simply add `lookfor=<input>` to the URL of the current page? Does your sample code above assume that the shiny app is hosted at `example.com`? Or do you want to actually change the URL in the URL bar entirely, including the domain name?

Comment: yes, i'm just trying to add the '?lookfor=<input>' to the current page! @DeanAttali

Comment: I was reading now your "Shiny tips & tricks for improving your apps and solving common problems" (great work, by the way!). I've seen the "Navigation in a Shiny app (forward/backwards in history)" , but i don't need all of that navigation history, just to add the '?lookfor=<input$text>'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your replies to my comment, what you're looking for is the `updateQueryString` function.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("query_text", "Type something:"),
  actionButton(inputId = 'query_button', label = "Search")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$query_button, {
    updateQueryString(paste0("?lookfor=", input$query_text))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot and great (and inspiring) work with Shiny =)